# fetch data from multiple tables using single query

Tags: mysql, join

[image: Database sample ER Diagram]

G'day everyone,

This is my first question to this community, as I am stuck for this task in the company where I am working as part time intern. I am very new to working with SQL and can't figure out the solution.

Consider we have following 5 tables in the DB: (removing irrelevant fields)

(image of ERD also attached)

```
desc jobs;
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name                  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| job_queue_id          | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| job_action_id         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id               | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

desc organisations;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| enabled    | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 1       |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

desc job_queues;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| organisation_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

desc attached_files;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| kind       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| location   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

desc job_attached_files;
+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| job_id           | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| attached_file_id | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now I have to fetch 
jobs.jobid, jobs.name, 
attached_files.id, attached_files.kind, attached_files.location
where the job has the organisation name "organisation1" which has ID "1".

The job table has job_queues id job_queues has got organisation id, organisations has got organisation name.

In simple words, I need to get all jobs from job table (and its relevant data from attached_files) where organisation name = organisation 1.

I don't know if I have stated and explained the question correctly and using right/professional approach, but it would be highly appreciated if you could figure out a single mega query to join all these tables and fetch the desired result.

Cheers,
Khan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the above requirement, following query should work.

```
SELECT j.jobid, j.name, af.id, af.kind, af.location 
FROM jobs j
INNER JOIN job_queues jq ON jq.id = j.job_queue_id
INNER JOIN organisations o ON o.id = jq.organisation_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN job_attached_files jaf ON jaf.job_id = j.id
INNER JOIN attached_files af ON af.id = jaf.attached_file_id
WHERE o.Id = 1
```

P.S: I am posting this query without any testing, so if there are any compilation errors or any unwanted results, please correct the query if you want or notify me, so that I can edit my answer accordingly

Answer (score -1):

Unless I misunderstand your question, you just want to join more than 1 table like on this other post?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995000/sql-inner-join-more-than-two-tables